# Can't set height on extJS Window

Tags: javascript, extjs

Regardless of what height argument I use, my window keeps a steady height of about 250px.  The console.log statement outputs 600 when I pass 600 to show, e.g. `getIFrameWindow().show({height: 600})`, so I know my height argument is being passed and received correctly, but my window doesn't render with it's correct height.

```
getIframeWindow : function () {
    return {
        show :function(args) {
            args=args||{};
            win = new Ext.Window({ 
                width    :args.width||200,
                height   :args.height||200,
                items    :[{
                    border      : false,
                    xtype       : 'iframepanel',
                    defaultSrc  : args.src||'_blank.htm'
                }]
            });
            console.log(win.height);
            win.show();
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

> ```
>             width    :args.width * 1.0 ||200,
>             height   :args.height * 1.0 ||200,
> ```

args.width and args.height will become numbers

Comment: Thanks, that would have saved me removing the quotes in all my calls to show().  I just learnt that trick a few weeks ago, but it's all too much JavaScript at once. ;-)